# Spring security behind Apache reverse proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, spring-security, reverse-proxy

I have my Spring-boot app behind Apache proxy.
My app is working on `http` and SSL related tasks are handled by proxy server.

I'm using Spring-security's login page.
Below is my security configurations:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin", true);

    }
```

So as a person with Admin authority login successfully I redirect to /admin.
This was working fine until I used apache proxy.

Before using proxy it was working fine.

> ( http://myhost/login >> after successful login redirects To >> http://myhost/admin )

After using proxy:

> ( https://myhost/login >> after successful login redirects To >> http://myhost/admin )

The main issue is that it redirecting to `http` instead of `https`.

Below is my apache proxy config:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

My question is how can I redirect to `https` after login.

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Apache Proxy setup is limited, however based on my understanding, you will need to enable **SSLEngine** in order to support SSL Protocol:

The documentation:

**SSLEngine Directive**

```
Description:    SSL Engine Operation Switch
Syntax: SSLEngine on|off|optional
Default:    SSLEngine off
Context:    server config, virtual host
Status: Extension
Module: mod_ssl
```

> This directive toggles the usage of the SSL/TLS Protocol Engine. This
> is should be used inside a  section to enable SSL/TLS for
> a that virtual host. By default the SSL/TLS Protocol Engine is
> disabled for both the main server and all configured virtual hosts.

**Example**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on
#...
</VirtualHost>
```

> In Apache 2.1 and later, SSLEngine can be set to optional. This
> enables support for RFC 2817, Upgrading to TLS Within HTTP/1.1. At
> this time no web browsers support RFC 2817.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#page-header